# Conditional Formatting based on another cell loop

Tags: vba, excel

i have written a code where whenever value gets changes in a cell, another cell gets Highlighted, however in the below code it's working fine.
unfortunately if amount is below or upto 500 it correctly highlights the cell B29:C29 when the next amount falls 1500 in cell C15 then B31:C31 gets highlighted however B29:C29 is also there i need before any other macro applied first one needs to clear .

```
Sub Highlight_Cells()

If Range("C18") >= "500" Then
Range("B29:C29").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If Range("C18") >= "501" And Range("C18") <= "1000" Then
Range("B30:C30").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If Range("C18") >= "1001" And Range("C18") <= "2000" Then
Range("B31:C31").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If Range("C18") >= "2001" And Range("C18") <= "5000" Then
Range("B32:C32").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If Range("C18") > "5000" Then
Range("B33:C33").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: _"...when the next amount falls 1500 in cell C15..."_ I do not see any reference to `C15` at all in your supplied code.

Comment: Do you realize that Excel's built-in [Conditional Formatting can format a cell based on the value of another cell](https://www.google.ca/search?q=conditional+formatting+based+on+another+cell)?  ...you're not the first person who's tried to re-write functionality that's alreadyt built-in to Excel.

Comment: @ashleedawg It's possible (although unlikely given the state of his question's rather low complexity) that OP only wants to trigger the color changes upon certain events.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs -- *Perhaps.*  Or perhaps this is an [incorrectly communicated] [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat your colors like a switch. If they are on, then they won't turn off unless you tell it to.

Try this

```
Sub Highlight_Cells()

    If Range("C18") >= "500" Then
        Range("B29:C29").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Range("B29:C29").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If

    If Range("C18") >= "501" And Range("C18") <= "1000" Then
        Range("B30:C30").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Range("B30:C30").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If

    If Range("C18") >= "1001" And Range("C18") <= "2000" Then
        Range("B31:C31").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Range("B31:C31").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If

    If Range("C18") >= "2001" And Range("C18") <= "5000" Then
        Range("B32:C32").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Range("B32:C32").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If

    If Range("C18") > "5000" Then
        Range("B33:C33").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Range("B33:C33").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Still its not up to the mark what i was looking for , i have a code that runs for 10000s of rows in a loop and for every there would be a different amt when i run that its not changing the cells color i need to First Condition "If Range("C18") < "500" Then
        Range("B29:C29").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Range("B29:C29").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If"       it immidiately clear the clolor til it reaches the next condition there are thousands of forms have been created ,     please excuse me for my english .

Comment: also when i used the above code when value is 500 Cells B29:C29 & B32:C32 are highlighting together , added any value between 500 and 1000  B29:C29 & B33:C33 are highlighting even we  on 500 B29:C29 , between 500 to 100 ,B30 :C30 should be highlighted

Comment: thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/5781745/k-d%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%a0%c9%aas it works when i add $ before C18